# SSMA - How to see the new Tables created on Oracle Schema?

Tags: oracle

I have a project to migrate Oracle schema and its objects to SQL Server on SSMA.
I created a new table on the Oracle schema I am migrating, but I cannot see that table on SSMA.

I tried "Refresh from Database" on SSMA and it doesn't show up either. I receive the message: *Nothing to process by this operation, because all objects are equal*

When I open the schema on SQL Developer, I can see the table under the schema on Oracle

Comment: Does the user you are connecting as in SSMA have READ/SELECT privileges on the new table?

Comment: @EJEgyed -Yes, it does.

Comment: I ended up having to create a new Project to see the new changes made by the schema. That sorted for me.